# Property #<propertyname> from class <class> is not implemented

Tags: typescript

I have an abstract class with a private field `#recordNumber`, which is typed `null | string` since one is not present for creation operations, however, every record type needs to have support for this, thus the abstract class, which I've included below.

```js
export abstract class AbstractRecord {

    #recordNumber: (null | string);

    protected constructor() {
        this.#recordNumber = null;
    }

    get recordNumber(): (null | string) {
        return this.#recordNumber;
    }

    set recordNumber(
        arg: (null | string)
    ) {
        this.#recordNumber = arg;
    }

}
```

When I go to implement this class, TypeScript complains **Property #recordNumber from class AbstractRecord is not implemented**.

Below is one of the classes I am attempted to have inherit from the `AbstractRecord` class.

```js
class UserRecord extends AbstractRecord {

    #firstName: string;
    #lastName: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    get firstName(): string {
        return this.#firstName;
    }

    set firstName(
        arg: string
    ) {
        this.#firstName = arg;
    }

    get lastName(): string {
        return this.#lastName;
    }

    set lastName(
        arg: string
    ) {
        this.#lastName = arg;
    }

    get fullName(): string {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
}
```

If I set `#recordNumber` to optional via `#recordNumber?` the child class no longer complains, but then I have to update the getter to return `this.#recordNumber || null`, which seems redundant since I initialize it to `null` in the constructor. It is also worth noting that TypeScript doesn't complain about the class and builds just fine. I'm sure I'm likely overlooking something, but I'm completely stumped as to what that would be.

Comment: Why don't you initialise it then and there? `#recorderNumber: string = null`? Also why not in initialise it to a string?

Comment: @somethinghere because the Database will complain if we set it to an empty string for create operations. It must be `null`. Additionally, our team's standards are not to initialize nullable values in-line like that, but even if I did initialize it in-line, it still complains, so it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Where is the error? https://shorturl.at/cjqW4
Please create a minimum repro example there

Comment: Right now the error you mentioned does not appear. This is therefore not an [mre], and we can't help you. Please [edit] to provide code that clearly demonstrates your issue when we copy and paste it into a standalone IDE.

Comment: Then I guess this is some issue with Webstorm, because I copied the code identically to what is causing the error when I pasted it here. The only thing I failed to mention, which could be important, is my Typescript version, which is 5.4.3.